# Change value type of bound datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010, datagridviewcolumn

I am binding data to a datagridview from a MSSQL database, there are mixed datatypes and I think vb.net by default sets the valuetype of the column/cell based on the data.

My requirement is that I want all the columns to have the value type of string.

I tried doing the following, before & after binding the data.

```
datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
colQty.ValueType = GetType(String)
```

Comment: Can you Cast the data to type of string during the binding? Maybe loop through the data and add it too a new column?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ColumnType` when the column is created. You can do this in code, or using the Designer in Visual Studio. It is worth noting that once a column is created [at run time] the `ColumnType` cannot be changed. You can of course add new columns as needed at run-time:

```
Dim col as New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
datagridview1.Columns.Add(col)
```

Changing a `ColumnType` in the designer can be accomplished From the *DataGridView Tasks* fly-out menu as shown below:  
[image: DataGridView Tasks]

---

[image: DataGridView Edit Columns]